# How to put Multiple Views inside Material design Collapsing-Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using the collapsing-toolbar in an Activity.I want to display a list in it, I am using a RecyclerView for that.This is working fine.But now I want to display a button below the Recyclerview.As I red some where We can put only one scrollable element inside collpasing-toolbar layout. I already have a Recyclerview how can I put a button below that ? I know I can put multiple views if I use nestedScrollview but it is not working with Recyclerview.

## What I tried

I tried to use nested-scrollview to display both recyclerview and button but recyclerview is not working inside nested scrollview.Following is my layout xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.andy.app.util.ui.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/Icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/groupIcon"
                android:background="@drawable/coll_toolbar_image_gradient" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button scroll with the view, you can add a button as the last row to your RecyclerView. Just insert the button layout with proper ViewHolder and override RecyclerView's getItemViewType(int position) method to inflate proper view and bind it.

If you want a static button, just wrap your RecyclerView with any suitable layout, like LinearLayout and add the button as you normally would.